# Foundation: How to include a chunk of HTML, ie, header, in all pages?

Tags: html, include, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation, I have a top-bar type header, and footer too, that I want to include in all pages. The site is static, what's the best way to achieve this?

Something like?

```
<!--#include virtual="/header.html" -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery to handle this :

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(function(){
         $("#header").load("navigation.html"); 
     });
});
</script> 

<div id="header"></div>
```